# router.events doesn't work properly with async in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm using this code to dynamic title

```
this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map(() => this.activatedRoute),
    map(route => {
        while (route.firstChild) {
            route = route.firstChild;
        }
        return route;
    }),
    filter(route => route.outlet === "primary"),
    mergeMap(route => route.data)
).subscribe(data => this.title = data.title || "");
```

and view: `{{title}}`

I wanted to refactor this part (to have `async` instead `subscribe`)
So I did:

```
this.title = this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEn
    mapTo(this.activatedRoute),
    map(route => {
        while (route.firstChild) {
            route = route.firstChild;
        }
        return route;
    }),
    filter(route => route.outlet === "primary"),
    mergeMap(route => route.data),
    pluck("title")
);
```

and view: `{{title | async}}`

But when I open page via URL, or even refresh the page then `title` is null. It works only when I navigate directly on page (by menu, buttons etc).

I don't know why it was working properly with `subscribe` and it doesn't with `async`.

I was even trying only with log, but it's the same issue, title is not appearing at the beginning.

```
this.title = this.router.events.pipe(
    tap(() => console.log("test"));
)
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue in angular 7 - i.e. wanting to use `async` (rather than `subscribe`) with `this.router.events.pipe`.

I solved it using `startWith` (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/startwith.html) so I could capture the initial loading event as well as `NavigationEnd` events.

Here's the relevant code fragment:

```
  this.router.events.pipe(
    startWith('Initial load'),
    filter(event => event === 'Initial load' || event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    // rest of code here
  );
```

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue with Angular 10. Ugly, but works.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a race condition. The template doesn't always get a chance to subscribe before the router events have completed. You might be able to handle this by [replaying the router events](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) so new subscribers (like the `async` directive) receive events that they may have missed.